# Reusing Fragment in multiple tabs

Tags: java, android

i will try my best to explain.
Lets say there are 3 tabs in my app.
Right now

- Tab 1 inflates fragment 1,
- Tab 2 inflates fragment 2,
- Tab 3 inflates fragment 3.

I don't want to use three fragments because the code is being fully reused in all 3 except 1 function i.e populatelist
what I planned on doing was just using fragment 1 with three different functions and implement a logic to check

- if tab 1, run populatelist1
- if tab 2, run populatelist2
- if tab 3,run populatelist3

I managed to do it by using viewpage . addOnPageChangeListener, This works but the problem is it is slowing down the app since list only gets populated when user clicks on the tab. Its not prepopulated like having 3 different fragments.

so I want to know is there a way to get Tab position and prepopulated the list on those positions? This way whether user switches to tab 2 or not the list will be present there just like it is when we have 3 different fragments.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use one ViewModel for all fragments.
its simple and best practice.

Comment: Shaheer Just to be sure, I want to use ONLY ONE fragment for all 3 tabs. This fragment will dynamically grab data based on the tab position. will using view model overcome the delay fragment will tab to populate data one a tab is selected ? if I use 3 different fragments there is no delay. Its lighting fast.